# Resolve not returning vlaue to controller if in separate file/module

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

FILE [myapp.js]

```
$stateProvider.state('view6', {
       resolve: {simpleObj: function(){ return {'value':"hello"}; }}
       controller:'MyCtrl6'
        });
```

Fails to pass resolved dependency to MyCtrl6 when MyCtrl6 exists in a separate file/module.

FILE [ controllers.js ]

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl6',['$scope',function($scope,simpleObj) {
        console.log(simpleObj.value);
        }]);
```

OUTPUT: 'undefined'

However the following works:

```
 $stateProvider.state('view6', {
       resolve: {simpleObj: function(){ return {'value':"hello"}; }
       controller:function(simpleObj){console.log(simpleObj.value);}
        });
```

Please forgive cut 'n paste omissons but I think this should convey the issue at question.

Thanks-

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a wrong type of arguments:

```
.controller('MyCtrl6',['$scope',function($scope,simpleObj) {
```

while we should see

```
.controller('MyCtrl6',['$scope', 'simpleObj' ,function($scope,simpleObj) {
```

which also should answer why this is working:

```
controller:function(simpleObj){
```

because we do have used different notation to pass the object into Controller

Comment: Thanks, however when I try that I simply get an error on simpleObj undefined/not loaded.  Seems to unresolved dependency is triggering an issue.  Seems paradoxical to me

Comment: It would be nice to see your complete code, and maybe in a plunker... then we can check what is the real issue. Because the params, declared, and expected - must fit togehter, or you will recieve wrongly instantiated controller. And also, ther resolve function must be correct, because it is working with *inlined* controller. And finally - there should be comma at the end of the resolve statement. simply - plunker with repeatable error will speed up finding the problem

Answer (score 1):

Seems I was calling the controller within the partial template

```
div ng-controller='MyCtrl3'
```

Apparently this can create some chaos with resolves when you are defining the controller in the stateProvider route definition.

Who knew?